# Перевод RecyclerView в нижнее положение при открытии клавиатуры

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Здравствуйте.

Есть `Layout` в котором находится `RecyclerView` и `Footer`, привязанный к нижней части экрана. Сама разметка:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/listChat"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:layout_above="@+id/listFooter"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/listFooter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/messageInput"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="textShortMessage"
        android:lines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:hint="Введите сообщение"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/sendButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

В манифесте:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MessagingActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

Проблема заключается в том, что я не могу перевести `RecyclerView` в нижнее состояние при открытии клавиатуры. Т.е. его положение остается таким же, каким было до открытия клавиатуры. До этого тут был `ListView` и все работало нормально.

Если наглядно, то выглядит изначально все выглядит так:

[image: 1st image]

При нажатии на `EditText` сейчас выглядит так:

[image: 2nd image]

Но нужно, чтобы выглядело так:

[image: 3rd image]

Пробовал ставить `onClickListener` на `EditText` и с задержкой вызывать

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(chatRecyclerAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
```

Но срабатывает оно через раз. Пробовал также менять различные атрибуты у `RecyclerView`, но успеха не принесло. Возможно, кто-то знает, как это реализовать.

Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `android:stackFromBottom="true"` для RecyclerView.

Comment: @YuraIvanov тоже пробовал - не помогло

Comment: @ahgpoug, а если `adjustPan` вместо `adjustResize` попробовать?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да, теперь нормально. Я так понимаю, что `toolbar` всегда скрывается при использовании `adjustPan`?

Comment: @ahgpoug, не могу сказать определённо. Думаю, это зависит от того как тулбар сделан. Если он в CoordinatorLayout, то, думаю, должен скрываться. Если прямо в разметку его поместить над recyclerView, то, может быть, и не уберётся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего поможет изменение в манифесте для активити `adjustResize` на `adjustPan`

Comment: Я понимаю, что вопрос уже давно закрыт, но только что обнаружил, что при открытой клавиатуре и `adjustPan`, `RecyclerView` не скроллится до самого верха. При этом до самого верха не хватает как раз расстояния раскрытой клавиатуры. Возможно ли что-то с этим сделать?